# How to restore Chrome "Person" bookmarks, settings, etc

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9 and somehow deleted one of the "People" profiles, and have lost my workflow terribly because it contained many settings and all bookmarks, etc.

I don't think I was logged in to a Google account at the time.

Is there any way to get this back? I've searched all over my user and system libraries, to no avail.

Comment: If you are logged into Google, do you have a profile saved there? You might be able to restore from the last time you signed in? Also, for Mac don't you have Time Machine to restore files?

Comment: Hi. I was not logged into Google at the time, and use a different process for backup, which unfortunately hasn't been used in a month. From where would I restore should I be able to find a backup? Thank you.

Comment: If you sign in to Chrome (to your Google Account) you can sync your profile back to the browser. What will be restored is whatever the last back on Google is. Perhaps that is better than nothing. Seems like a case of needing recent backups.

Comment: @Sathya♦  I don't see a "[tag-cleanup-request]" for "people".  It may be a lousy tag, but are people allowed to unilaterally burninate tags they dislike, without going through the Meta process?